# How to make NodeJS return a response to an XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, post, backend

I am building a database app, and a key component would be allowing clients to create and manipulate their users' accounts. For efficient functionality, I would want to create a way for their front end to send a POST request via `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`. However, my problem is that the request is not processed by my back end and demo front end. Here is my code:

Front end javascript:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// we defined the xhr

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4) {
    console.log(this.response);
  }
};

xhr.open('POST', 'https://PlasticStudiousCells.programprodigy.repl.co/add-user', true);
xhr.send(
  JSON.stringify({
    'user': 'lol',
    'key': 'QKsP2s23LP',
    'data': {
      'name': 'lol',
      'email': 'lol@lol.com',
      'password': 'lol'
    }
  })
);
```

My back end code:

```
app.post('/add-user', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  let user = JSON.parse(req.body);
  let keys = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/home/runner/PlasticStudiousCells/dbs/keys.json'));
  if (keys[encrypt(user.key)]) {
    try {
      addUser(keys[encrypt(user.key)], user.user, user.data);
      res.status(200).send('User successfully added.');
      console.log(user.user +' successfully added.');
    } catch(err) {
      res.status(404).send(err);
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
})
```

I assure you that addUser is a defined function and works.

Comment: I would be very surprised if this (a) didn't work **and** (b) didn't log an error on the browser's developer tools console **and** (c) didn't log an error on the console where you are using Node.js to run the server side program. Please read [ask] and make sure you include debugging information in your question.

Comment: `let user = JSON.parse(req.body);` is a red flag that suggests you haven't read the Express API documentation for `req.body`.

Comment: I had tried the `let user = JSON.parse(req.body)` because nothing else was working and it would give no hint whatsoever as to what the problem was. And yes, none of (a), (b), or (c) worked.

Comment: What do you mean by "the request is not processed by my back end", the request doesn't reach the backend? The backend's route callback isn't called at all? Or all of that works well but your code is not responding the way you want? Does the console.log output anything to your console?

Comment: I bet you have no body parser middleware installed, and you also need to set the right "content-type" on your client side.

Comment: @Gonzalingui The console.log outputs nothing, and the backend at /add-user is not called. I believe that my request is not going through, but now that I added a request header of application/json, I get a DOMException, saying it cannot execute setRequestHeader because the object's state must be opened.

Comment: @Marc I do have the body-parser require line, and now it generates a DOMException when I added a content-type header on the front-end.

Comment: First make sure the request gets to the correct API route, check your browser's Network panel to see if you get a 404 error code or anything else.